# Issue with linking new node to Linked lists in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new to C and new to programming as well and I've just started looking at linked lists.

```
static struct post {
    char * str;
    struct post * next;
}
head = {0, NULL};


int stringdb_add(const char * str) {
    int pos = 0;
    struct post * new_input = (struct post * ) malloc(sizeof(struct post));
    new_input - > str = (char * ) malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    if (head.next == NULL) {
        strcpy(new_input - > str, str);
        new_input - > next = NULL;
        head.next = new_input;
    } else {
        while (head.next - > next) {
            ++pos;
            head.next = head.next - > next;
        }
        strcpy(new_input - > str, str);
        new_input - > next = NULL;
        head.next - > next = new_input;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

The function "stringdb_add" is supposed to return the position the new node has been placed in, but when I test the function I only get (00111111....).

This is probably because the list never links properly.

Comment: You get a +1 for trying .. But might get a -1 for indentation - sort it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> while (head.next->next) {
>    ++pos;
>    head.next = head.next->next;        
> }
> ```

You are permanently changing `head.next` which is surely not what you want. You probably want something like:

```
struct post *p = &head;
while (p->next->next)
/* ... */
```

---

Nitpick: `strcpy(new_input->str, str)` can be in a single place, before the `if`.

Comment: Okay, i totaly got it working now, the whole p pointer made everything easier. thanks for your help and a really qucik answer! :)